# Метод SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#

1. Метод SelectedIndexChanged контрола вызывается сам при загрузке формы на которой он расположен? или он не вызывается вместе с формой на которой он расположен?
2. Как избежать эту ошибку?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Наверное, Вы в Form Load инициализируете combobox3, вот его значение и меняется.
2. У Вас в textbox1 введено число в неправильном формате. Кстати, формат, грубо говоря, зависит от выбранного в ОС языка. Например в английской ОС вы должны вводить "3**.**14", а в русской - "3**,**14". Есть и другие способы решить эту проблему.

Comment: А у меня число без точек и запятых, я его задаю **textBox1.Text = "345";**. И в методе **Form1_Load** эта же запись           **F = 1000 * Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);** работает и переменная F принимает значение. ошибки не возникает. А в методе **comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged** ошибку выдает.

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте в отладчике или выведите на печать реальное значение textBox1.Text. Может быть в тот момент, когда происходит конверсия, это просто null? Если так, то надо добавить проверку

```
if (textBox1.Text != null) {
}
```